# Create a secure POST link in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm wondering if there's any simple way to create a link to submit a POST request to the server by using some Express.js technique or plugin.

It is also a way to secure more critical actions such as deletion of users. Adding also CSRF protection.

This is quite simple to do in some PHP frameworks such as CakePHP (with its [postLink](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink) helper).

The way I'm doing it right now is by creating a hidden form by myself and adding in the html link an event to submit the form:

```
<form action="/users/delete/{{user.id}}" method="post" name="deleteUser{{ user.id }}" style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}" />
</form> 

<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')) { document.deleteUser{{ user.id }}.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">
    Delete
</a>
```

This is exactly the way it works in CakePHP framework as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own way to deal with them by using jQuery (but could also be done with javascript  as well).

In my case, any link I want to send by POST will have to:

- Contain the class `postLink`.
- Contain the destination URL in the `href` attribute.
- Contain the CSRF token in the `data-csrf` attribute.
- Optionally contain the `data-confirm` attribute to specify a message to show as a confirmation before sending the POST request.

A link in the view would look like so:

```
<a href="/reject/23" class="postLink" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to reject this item?" data-csrf="NdiuZynW-thVmMqYPZqFFGxGcInQZn35mDf8">
    Reject
</a>
```

Or without the confirm attribute:

```
<a href="/reject/23" class="postLink" data-csrf="NdiuZynW-thVmMqYPZqFFGxGcInQZn35mDf8">
    Reject
</a>
```

The needed jQuery code is the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.postLink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var csrf = $(this).data('csrf');
    var confirmed = false;

    if(typeof $(this).data('confirm') !== 'undefined'){
        if(confirm($(this).data('confirm'))){
            confirmed = true;
        };
    }else{
        confirmed = true;
    }

    if(confirmed){
        $('body').append('\
            <form action="'+ url +'" method="post" name="postLink" style="display:none;">\
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="'+ csrf +'" />\
            </form>\
        ');

        $('form[name="postLink"').submit();
    }
});
```

Basically what it does is applying the same technique of creating a form for each POST link that I mentioned in my question. The only difference is that I don't have to be bothered to create a form every time I want to create  POST link.

This way the form will be created dynamically and appended to the `body`. Then submitted.

To make it secure I made use of the [CSRF module for express.js](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf).

If you don't need a secure POST link, then you probably could use [the postLink plugin for jQuery](https://code.google.com/p/postlink/).

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to create link to a POST request you can make use of client side techniques like capturing the click using javascript and generate a ajax post request to the server, Inoder to avoid CSRF attacks express middlewares are available(https://github.com/expressjs/csurf)

Comment: Still being quite similar to what I posted. The only difference is that you deal with in javascript.

Comment: How would you do to post a link, and then redirect the user from the servers side route? This is what I have right now: http://paste.ofcode.org/ELbiuViYqjzyAm4YZMffmB but the server side is not able to redirect the user anywhere... I would have to do in the client side... which is not desirable.